# How to change color of parent sortable after it has been dragged

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm trying to change the color of a parent sortable list item from a sortable list. I would like to apply a change in color (red) after the parent has been dragged from the grey list to the bottom yellow lists. The children li's dragged from the top grey box will remain unaffected. I basically want to to indicate which li has been dragged from the top grey box.

I applied a toggleClass and css via jquery but had no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/equiroga/JkCua/1/

$(function () {
    $("#sortable1").sortable({
        helper: "clone",
        connectWith: ".sortable",

```
    start: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.item).show();
        clone = $(ui.item).clone();
        before = $(ui.item).prev();
        position = $(ui.item).index();
    },
    beforeStop: function (event, ui) {
        if ($(ui.item).closest('ul#sortable1').length > 0) $(this).sortable('cancel');
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        if (position == 0) $("#sortable1").prepend(clone);
        else before.after(clone);
    }
});

$(".sortable").sortable({connectWith: ".sortable:not('#sortable1')"});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Please, check http://jsfiddle.net/JkCua/6/

I just add:

```
        $("#sortable1>li").eq(position).css('background','red');
```

on the stop event.

Comment: thanks for taking the time. However, I'm trying to achieve the color effect on the parent sortable li that remains in the grey box. As an indicator that it has been dragged to the yellow boxes.

Comment: Dude you Rock! I will sing your praises with my guitar tonite. Thank you for taking the time and helping me out. Cheers.